# Can't Install Windows 10 1607 virtual machine Guest on Server 2008 R2 Host

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, windows-10

Trying to install the new Windows 10 1607 Enterprise OS as a virtual Machine using Hyper V on a Server 2008 R2 Host.

When I start the installer I get the Windows logo for 5 seconds.

Then the screen goes blank / black.

I would usually expect to see the Windows Installer options to select the Installation Language, Region and Keyboard settings. But I just see a black screen.

I get the following errors in the event viewer.
Application and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows -> Hyper-V-Worker -> Admin

Event ID: 23014

> Device 'Microsoft Synthetic Display Controller' in 'TESTWINDOWS10' is
>   loaded but has a different version from the server.  Server version
>   3.0 Client version 3.5 (Virtual machine ID 6C2F809F-69A0-4FED-A099-B1F64C57AD79). The device will work, but this
>   is an unsupported configuration. This means that technical support
>   will not be provided until this problem is resolved. To fix this
>   problem, upgrade the integration services. To upgrade, connect to the
>   virtual machine and select Insert Integration Services Setup Disk from
>   the Action menu.

Event ID: 12540

> 'TESTWINDOWS10' device Microsoft Synthetic Display Controller experienced a protocol error indicative of a deep system problem.  (Virtual machine ID 6C2F809F-69A0-4FED-A099-B1F64C57AD79)

Event ID: 11902

> 'TESTWINDOWS10' (Device 'Microsoft Synthetic Display Controller'): a unrecoverable internal error has occurred. (Virtual machine ID 6C2F809F-69A0-4FED-A099-B1F64C57AD79)

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official word from Microsoft is that Windows 10 is not a supported guest OS for a Server 2008 R2 host.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396